# C++ OSX stod causes crash even with try/catch OS 10.8.5 Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: macos, exception

Here is my function, I am just wrapping stod to prevent crashes for when "" or non-number is the input

```
double ToD(string n) { try { return stod(n); } catch (exception e) { return 0.0; } }
```

I am creating a cross-platform software. This does not crash on OSX 10.11 or Windows.

Comment: are you using `string` and `exception` or are you using `std::string` & `std::exception`?

Comment: I have in the code `using std::string` and `using std::exception`